# validate a dropdown list to get proper date based on the option selected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, drop-down-menu

**-** I have a **dropdown** List on which there are some options from which user can select one.

**- Options are 1 day, 1 week, 2 weeks, 1 month and 6 months**

**-** Now when I **select option 1 day**, **today's date should be incremented by one** and next date is shown.

**-** If I **select 1 week, the date falling after one week should be shown**.

**-** Now the problem is when I select an option it **sometimes shows date greater than 30/31**.

**-** I use below `javacript` function:

```
 function select_duration(ddlcupon) {

            var skillsSelect = document.getElementById("ddlcupon");
            var selectedText = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text;

            if (selectedText == "1 Day") {

                var currentTime = new Date();
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = currentTime.getDate() + 1;
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                var exdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

                document.getElementById('<%=txtEventDate.ClientID%>').value = exdate.toString();


            }
            if (selectedText == "1 Week") {

                var currentTime = new Date();
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = currentTime.getDate() + 7;
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                var exdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

                document.getElementById('<%=txtEventDate.ClientID%>').value = exdate.toString();
            }
            if (selectedText == "2 Weeks") {

                var currentTime = new Date();
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = currentTime.getDate() + 14;
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                var exdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                document.getElementById('<%=txtEventDate.ClientID%>').value = exdate.toString();
            }
            if (selectedText == "1 Month") {

                var currentTime = new Date();
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 2;
                var day = currentTime.getDate();
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                var exdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                document.getElementById('<%=txtEventDate.ClientID%>').value = exdate.toString();
            }
            if (selectedText == "6 Months") {

                var currentTime = new Date();
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 7;
                var day = currentTime.getDate();
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                var exdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                document.getElementById('<%=txtEventDate.ClientID%>').value = exdate.toString();
            }
```

**-** Can someone help me in getting a **proper date?**

Comment: I believe moment.js is going to be your friend here. Its a really good javascript date manipulation tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this

```
var dt1 = new Date();    
var dt2 = new Date(dt1.getTime() + (86400000 * numberOfDay) );
```

if your date is incremented by one day try

```
var dt2 = new Date(dt1.getTime() + (86400000 * 1 ) ); //so on
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're incrementing day, month and year. So, if the month is 12, you'll get 13. You could work directly with milliseconds. For example:

```
var d = new Date('01/31/2013'); // Thu Jan 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)
var addDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var currentMs = d.getTime();
d.setTime(currentMs + addDay);
console.log(d); // Fri Feb 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is a handy script for all kinds of JavaScript date manipulation.

The syntax to add n number of days to current day is

```
// Add 3 days to Today
Date.today().add(3).days();
```

In this case adds 3 days to the current date.